# Can Android automatically add letterboxes for ignore rounded corners, notches, etc?

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]

```
public class MainPanel extends View {
    Drawable bg;

    public MainPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        bg.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        bg.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Is there code for run app as always classic rectangle on any cutout? Left picture shows rounded corners if cutout is default.